# Way to close TCP Connection and Exit Application

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming, tcplistener

This is a TCP Program which receives data from a TCP connection, then parse it and transfer it to another TCP connection. When I exit application, it doesn't work. It will remain as a process in the system.

As I am not a very experienced developer, can someone please help me to find the error in this code..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace Machine_Feeder
{
    public partial class FeederControlMonitor : Form
    {
        TcpListener Listener = null;
        public string Status = string.Empty;
        public Thread T = null;
        public FeederControlMonitor()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
         }

        private void FeederControlMonitor_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtStatus.Text = "Feeder waiting for data...";
            ThreadStart Ts = new ThreadStart(StartReceiving);
            T = new Thread(Ts);
            T.Start();
        }
        public void StartReceiving()
        {
            ReceiveTCP(9100);
        }
        public void ReceiveTCP(int portN)
        {

            try
            {
                Listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, portN);
                Listener.Start();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                File.WriteAllText(@"C:\\Drive\\ex.txt", ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
       try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Socket client = Listener.AcceptSocket();
                    var childSocketThread = new Thread(() =>
                    {
                        byte[] data = new byte[10000];
                        int size = client.Receive(data);
                        ParseData(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(data));
                        client.Close();
                    });
                    childSocketThread.Start();
                    }
                    Listener.Stop();
  }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                File.WriteAllText(@"C:\\Drive\\ex.txt", ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public void ParseData(string data)
        {
            var useFulData = data.Substring(data.IndexOf("F1")).Replace("  ", " ");// Space
            useFulData = useFulData.Remove(useFulData.IndexOf("<ETX>"));
            string[] delimeters = { "<DEL>", "<ESC>" };
            var listOfValues = useFulData.Split(delimeters, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();
            int pos = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < listOfValues.Count; i += 2, pos++)
            {
                listOfValues[pos] = listOfValues[i];
            }
            listOfValues.RemoveRange(pos, listOfValues.Count - pos);
            txtHealthCard.Invoke((Action)delegate { txtHealthCard.Text = listOfValues[0]; });
            txtCID.Invoke((Action)delegate { txtCID.Text = listOfValues[1]; });
            txtMedicalFitLocation.Invoke((Action)delegate { txtMedicalFitLocation.Text = listOfValues[2]; });
            txtGender.Invoke((Action)delegate { txtGender.Text = listOfValues[3]; });
            txtAge.Invoke((Action)delegate { txtAge.Text = listOfValues[4]; });
            txtPatientName.Invoke((Action)delegate { txtPatientName.Text = listOfValues[5]; });


            MyProtocolMaker(listOfValues[5], 
                listOfValues[4], 
                listOfValues[2], 
                listOfValues[3], 
                listOfValues[8], 
                listOfValues[1], 
                listOfValues[10], 
              );
        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Listener.Stop();
            T.Abort();
            this.Close();
        }
        private void MyProtocolMaker(
            string patientName,
            string patientAge,
            string mfitLocation,
            string gender,
            string healthCardNo,
           )
        {
            string feederInfo = "^^^P^PI" + healthCardNo + "^PN" + patientName + "^PA" + patientAge + "^PS" + gender + "^P7" + mfitLocation +"^_SS^^^_S";
            System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient clientSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 8001);
            NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(feederInfo);
            serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
            serverStream.Flush();
            serverStream.Close();
            clientSocket.Close();
         }

        private void FeederControlMonitor_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Listener.Stop();
            T.Abort();
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You problem is, that you are creating threads within the thread. These threads are keeping the application alive. Try marking them as background threads: *(This is red-tape solution)*

```
var childSocketThread = new Thread(() =>
{
    byte[] data = new byte[10000];
    int size = client.Receive(data);  // <-- the thread hangs on these and will block termination
    ParseData(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(data));
    client.Close();
});
childSocketThread.IsBackground = true;   // <---
childSocketThread.Start();
```

When thread are **not** marked as background *(default)*, they will block application termination. You should create a list to store the client threads, so you can exit those threads nicely.

---

**You should never abort a thread, unless there is no other way.** Instead of aborting, you should exit the `while` loop in the thread.

As nice way is using a `ManualResetEvent`:

*fields:*

```
private ManualResetEvent _terminating = new ManualResetEvent(false);
```

*in thread:*

```
while (_terminating.WaitOne(0))
{
    // thread code
}
```

*on exit:*

```
_terminating.Set();
T.Join();
```

---

*Sidenote: TCP is streaming, so just reading 10k of bytes ones, does not guarantee a complete packet.*